# Any npm modules that can create user friendly unqiue id's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I cannot to seem to find a good user friendly readable unique id generator for saving to orders to my backend.

I am aware of the timestamp method but thats just too long from what I've seen.

Comment: md5, uuid npm library

Comment: got a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

These are some useful packages you can use for generating unique id.

1. [nid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nid) (I will recommend this)
2. [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)
3. [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid)

Answer (score 0):

Without module, you can use Math.random method as well.

Example:

```
this.uid = "_" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
```